# Loading .svg file from web or local cache in Android

Tags: android, svg, android-glide, androidsvg

I'm using `Glide` to load `.png` image asynchronously.

`File file = Glide.with(context).load(location).downloadOnly(1024, 1024).get();`

In case of `.svg`, the file is created but it is not loading into `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

ImageView only accepts Bitmaps or VectorDrawables.

SVG is neither of the two, even if VectorDrawable descends from it.

Get a `PictureDrawable` from your `SVG` file. Then you need to create a `Bitmap` from the size of the `PictureDrawable` and give it to a `Canvas`.

```
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture()); 
currentBitmap = bitmap;
```

Comment: Actually, I need the file name after loading .svg file

Comment: We cant use .svg files , i convert them to xml then use them.

Comment: I'm using leaflet in Android and showing the image on webview. I'm loading the image from the local cache using glide then I'm returning the location of the local cache to leaflet. For `.svg` it won't work

Comment: I think first you have to convert .svg to bitmap then  returning the location of the local cache to leaflet.

Comment: then the question comes, how to load.svg file remotely. just like glide

Comment: Does the Glide SVG example not suit your needs? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg